# Error retrieving COM class factory - Class not registered

Tags: c#, asp.net, com

I'm trying to use the Mailroom Toolkit from Satori to standardize addresses, but every time I try to instantiate an instance of ZIPAssembly, I get the following exception.

> {Satori.MailRoomToolKit.US.USException (0x80040154 from
>   ZIPAssembly::.ctor): Retrieving the COM class factory for component
>   with CLSID {E1DD1DB5-CEAD-4C36-B2E1-EDEC0DA4C1AC} failed due to the
>   following error: 80040154 Class not registered (Exception from
>   HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)).    at
>   Satori.MailRoomToolKit.US.Interfaces.ZIPAssembly..ctor()

I've tried `regsvr32`, but I get the message `The module "MRTKUSAssembly.dll" was loaded but the entry-point DllRegisterServer was not found.`

I've also tried setting my project target to x86, but that doesn't do it either. Any other ideas? Similar posts have not helped.

Note that I'm running on a 64bit machine and have tried setting my project target to x86 running in the visual studio web server, and setting my project as AnyCPU and running under IIS.

Comment: Is IIS set to load 32 bit COM objects?

Comment: The error means that the dll you are trying to register is not a COM DLL, are you sure you are trying to register the right dll ?

Comment: @lvanzijl - you are right it is a .net assembly and I wouldn't think I would need to register it. I attempted this just because it's the first thing everyone says whenever I look up this error.

Comment: @Tetsujin no Oni - I enabled 32 bit applications in my app pool and it's screwing with another 3rd party dll now. I'll have to see if I can get past that one to know if it helps. I would think this would be the same as running it in the VS Web server tho, no?

Comment: I have a mail in to Satori. They claim the compiler settings need to target x86, however that does not work. Waiting to hear back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out in this case with the Mailroom Toolkit from Satori, you have to run an install locally before you can use the dll. Seems there are some underlying com components that the dll requires and those need to get installed/registered.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that this is the assembly where class factory resides in it means that it's a .net assembly that needs registering as COM component. You should look into [regasm](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tzat5yw6%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).

If it does work in Visual Studio it could be that Visual Studio did this registration for you, but you'll have to do this yourself in your deploy environment.

Comment: @lvanzijl, why would one try to register a .Net assembly as a COM component just to use it in .NET?

Comment: regasm has no affect. `RegAsm : warning RA0000 : No types were registered`